# caching of schema on Multi tenant APP, the schema is from a Single tenant APP (ROR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant

I have two ROR application one is Single Tenant and other is MultiTenant.

We have a way to access the schema of Single Tenant from MultiTenant System Using the Apartment switch.

Recently i had run a migration(Add a column) on couple of tables in Single Tenant App and tried to fetch the schema through MultiTenant App but i could see new column appearing.

I then restarted my multitenant app server then i was able to see the newly added column in the table.

Is there a way to avoid caching or immeaditely reflect the changes on DB on Single Tenant to MultiTenant.

say example :-
Table Person had ID,Username initially and Phone Number was added as part of Migration in Single Tenant App

I can only see Table Person with ID,Username still on SingleTenant until i restart the Multitenant app server.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer. 
model.reset_column_information